# Changing a child component in another component in a repeater

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a custom component in a repeater. This component has a child component which can be of two types depending on some conditions. What I did was use an UIComponent as a place holder.

In the repeated component, lets say RepeatedComponent :

```
<mx:VBox>
   <mx:UIComponent id="placeHolder"/>
</mx:VBox>
```

And I'm doing this in the component having the repeater :

```
// Function where I try to inject the child component :
private function getComponent():UIComponent{
            if(condition)
            {
                return new ChildComponentA(); 
            }
            else
            {
                return new ChildComponentB();
            }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:VBox>

    <mx:Repeater id="repeteur" 
                 recycleChildren="true" 
                 dataProvider="{arrayBeneficiaires}" >

        <components:RepeatedComponent id="repeatedComponent"
                                      beneficiaire="{repeteur.currentItem}"
                                      placeHolder="{getComponent()}"/>

    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:VBox>
```

When I place breakpoints in the functions called at creationComplete, I can see that the component assigned to placeHolder is correct but it does not show on my display. I tried refreshing by calling invalidateDisplayList in every place I can think of but it does not seem to work.
Any ideas would be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the value from `getComponent()` is never added to the stage.  ie - setting the value of `placeHolder` to something is not the same as calling addChild(getComponent()).

Therefore, the following would work:

```
 <mx:Repeater id="repeteur" 
             recycleChildren="true" 
             dataProvider="{arrayBeneficiaires}" >

    <components:RepeatedComponent id="repeatedComponent"
                                  beneficiaire="{repeteur.currentItem}"
                                  creationComplete="getComponent(repeatedComponent)"/>

</mx:Repeater>




 private function getComponent(parent:RepeatedComponent):void {
        if(condition)
        {
            parent.addChild(new ComponentA());
        }
        else
        {
            parent.addChild(new ComponentB()); 
       }
  }
```

Note, that in this scenario, you don't need the placeHolder UIComponent (which doesn't really serve any purpose).

However, I'd reccommend that this logic be moved inside `RepeatedComponent`, as it appears as though this decision is the responsibility of the component, rather than the parent.

Then the code becomes much cleaner:

```
 <mx:Repeater id="repeteur" 
             recycleChildren="true" 
             dataProvider="{arrayBeneficiaires}" >

    <components:RepeatedComponent id="repeatedComponent"
                                  beneficiaire="{repeteur.currentItem}" />

</mx:Repeater>


<!-- RepeatedComponent.mxml -->
<mx:VBox>
   <mx:UIComponent id="placeHolder"/>
</mx:VBox>

<mx:Script>
     private var _beneficiaire:Object
     public function get beneficiaire():Object {
         return _beneficiaire;
     }
     public function set beneficiaire(value:Object):void {
          _beneficiaire = value;
          createSubComponent();
     }
     private function createSubComponent():void
        if(condition)
        {
            parent.addChild(new ComponentA());
        }
        else
        {
            parent.addChild(new ComponentB()); 
        }
    }

</mx:Script>
```

Comment: Explicitly adding the child was indeed the solution. Thanks!